# How to use matplotlib tight layout with Figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I found `tight_layout` function for pyplot and want to use it. In my application I embed matplotlib plots into Qt GUI and use figure and not pyplot. Is there any way I can apply `tight_layout` there? Would it also work if I have several axes in one figure?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Just call `fig.tight_layout()` as you normally would. (`pyplot` is just a convenience wrapper. In most cases, you only use it to quickly generate figure and axes objects and then call their methods directly.)

There shouldn't be a difference between the `QtAgg` backend and the default backend (or if there is, it's a bug).

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#-- In your case, you'd do something more like:
# from matplotlib.figure import Figure
# fig = Figure()
#-- ...but we want to use it interactive for a quick example, so 
#--    we'll do it this way
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat, start=1):
    ax.set_title('Test Axes {}'.format(i))
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')

plt.show()
```

### Before Tight Layout

[image]

### After Tight Layout

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat, start=1):
    ax.set_title('Test Axes {}'.format(i))
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]