# Matplotlib:subplots fonts overlap

Tags: matplotlib

I want to make 21 subplots using the matplotlib. In some of the plots, fonts of axis are overlapping on the X-axis but X-axis labels are OK. For example, X-axis of one plot has value of (0,10,2) and adjoining plot has value of (0.001,0.010,0.002) so in subplots, 10 (on first X-axis) is overlap with 0.001 (X-axis of adjoining plot). If any one know about it then please reply me.

Many thanks

-Viral

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try:

- Adjust subplots so that there is more wspace and hspace
- Adjust xlim/ylim manually to make sure there's no overlap (tricky)
- Use tight_layout (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603230/how-to-use-matplotlib-tight-layout-with-figure))