# How to rearrange subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I rearrange my subplots where the plots don't overlap? Appreciate also if there are tips on how to increase the plot sizes :)

Here's my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax1.plot(df[['data1A','data1B','data1C']])
ax1.set_title('group1')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax2.plot(df[['data2A','data2B']])
ax2.set_title('group2')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax3.plot(df['data3A'])
ax3.set_title('group3')
```

[image]

Comment: Use plt.tight_layout() at the end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use matplotlib tight layout with Figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603230/how-to-use-matplotlib-tight-layout-with-figure)

Comment: `fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3) `
In this case, you only need to set the height, but for multiple graphs with multiple columns, you can also adjust the spacing between the graphs.