# How to adjust the position of title and x,y axis in each figure in order to make it suitable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

There are much more information overlap in my figure, I want to make it more clear, how to modify my code?

```
df = pd.read_excel('biodye_24samples.xlsx', header=None)
x_coord =df.values[0, 1:] 
df_name = df.values[1:, 0]
df_val = df.values[1:,1:]


fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(1, 13):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 4, i)  
    ax.plot(x_coord, df_val[2*i - 2,],'r', label='SCI') 
    ax.plot(x_coord, df_val[2*i - 1,],'b', label='SCE') 
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength(nm)', fontsize = 10)
    plt.ylabel('Reflectance', fontsize = 10)
    plt.legend()
    plt.title(df_name[2*i - 2], fontsize = 10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `fig.tight_layout()` not work?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks lot, it indeed works, but each figure looks very small...

Comment: You could increase the `figsize` of the figure perhaps. `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(...,...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two recommendations:

- [`fig.tight_layout()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603230/how-to-use-matplotlib-tight-layout-with-figure) to fix the padding between and around the subplots.
- [Increase the `figsize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) of the figure: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(...,...))`, where the arguments are width and height in inches.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using constrained layout rather than `tight_layout`.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html  For simple things they are the same, but for more complex layouts constrained_layout usually works better.